# How to center only a child element from a container using Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with 2 children. First child is an icon and second is text. I want to align the icon left and the title center using Flexbox only.

The HTML code and the CSS code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #7D8F99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #9AADB8;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1AADA9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">icon</span>
  <span class="title">text</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eajosjoh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `margin: 0 auto;` to the `.title` will solve the problem

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #7D8F99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #9AADB8;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1AADA9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">icon</span>
  <span class="title">text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea! However, the `.title` is slightly off-center using this method.

Comment: Yes, but it's upto the requirement whether to center the element to the remaining space or to the center of its parent.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `position: absolute` and `left: 0` on the `.icon` would do the trick.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #7D8F99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  background-color: #9AADB8;
}

.icon {
  background-color: #1AADA9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">icon</span>
  <span class="title">text</span>
</div>
```

**Or**, if you wanted to use only flex, you could add an empty spacer element on the right side. The spacer element would need to have the same width as the `.icon` element. And honestly, adding an empty element for the sake of layout isn't a great option. So I'd recommend the first method.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #7D8F99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.title {
  background-color: #9AADB8;
}

.icon {
  background-color: #1AADA9;
  width: 30px;
}

.spacer {
  /* width must match icon width */
  width: 30px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">icon</span>
  <span class="title">text</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
</div>
```